# HTML template not found

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, angular-routing

I get page not found error when I try to load an injected page from my templates folder. index.html page is the page launched by default when I start the server and it also contains ng-view, so I can inject the pages specified in the angular config.

Here is my project structure:

```
 angular_routing/
      flask_service.py
      static/
        script.js
      templates/
        index.html
        home.html
        ....
```

This is my angular routing:

```
// configure our routes
    scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            })

            .otherwise({
                templateUrl: '/',
                controller: 'mainController'
            });
//            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

BTW, I tried prefixing the templateUrl with a '/' but it didn't work either.

Comment: are those templates reachable via browser?

Comment: yes, they are reachable

Comment: cool, can you please check what urls is Angular using to get the templates and compare them with the urls that the templates are reachable by? You can do it by observing server logs, or using Chrome's console Network tab

Comment: oops, i've misread your previous comment.. the templates are not reachable via browser.. say http://localhost:5000/templates/home.html makes the browser crash

Comment: what I am trying to do is very simple and I don't think it needs a Plunker.. I've got a few pages in html and by default I load index.html. index.html contains <div ng-view></div>. Whenever I request a url different from the default http://localhost:5000/#/ , I want to replace the ng-view with a different html page located in the templates folder.

Answer (score 1):

The templates folder is for template files that will be rendered by Jinja from Flask.  They are not served as normal static html files that would be accessible to Angular.  Move the Angular templates to the static folder and access them from there.  You can generate the urls with `url_for` if you're rendering the Angular routing code in a Jinja template.

```
templateUrl: '{{ url_for('static', filename='angular_templates/home.html') }}'
// or if the Angular is complete separate from Flask/Jinja,
// you'll have to just write out the path
templateUrl: 'static/angular_templates/home.html',
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if the router is accessing the right pages. You can do this in Chrome via the developer console, then the Network tab.

Comment: this is my request url http://localhost:5000/templates/home.html and therefore I get 404 not found